# How to start/stop autocomplete plugin by clicking an href?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, unbind

I am using jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1 by Joern Zaefferer.

Everything works fine on the code.

Documentation however is scarce. I am needing someone to help me find out how to turn the autocomplete 'on' or 'off' using an href link.

It seems the unautocomplete() function should work somehow to disable it but not sure how to call it correctly.

I use this to activate it when page is loaded:

```
$().ready(function() {
  $("#term").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    noCache: true,
    minChars: <?php echo $auto_char; ?>,
    selectFirst: false
  });
});
```

What I have done is added a "hide suggestions" link to the end of the returned results and am trying to disable the autocomplete when the user clicks it.

Comment: show the way you call the `.unautocomplete()` method and the HTML of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your HTML look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="term" />
...
<button id="hide">Hide suggestions</button>
```

You can call `$.unautocomplete` this way to disable the `#term` element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#term").unautocomplete();
  });
});
```

Or, I guess you can use this to disable all autocompletes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(":input").unautocomplete();
  });
});
```

Also, you may want to upgrade to a more recent version of the AutoComplete plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that this was [not available in the 1.1 release of the jQuery UI autocomplete plugin](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-autocomplete). It appears to have been a bug. It was fixed in the 1.8.3 jQuery UI release.

But you're not even using an older version of jQuery UI. Read below...

You're using the [deprecated 1.1 release written by Joern Zaefferer](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), judging by the code you've posted. This plugin was deprecated almost two years ago, and the link to the old plug-in has references that will guide you through any migration challenges.

The autocomplete plugin is now part of jQuery UI and is at version 1.8.20! I strongly suggest that you [upgrade to the latest version of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) and use that autocomplete plugin instead.

Afterwards, the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) shows that you can disable autocomplete by invoking the following method on the selector that autocomplete was originally bound to:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ disabled: true });
```

Keep in mind that you're basically using something that hasn't seen an upgrade in a very long time, and as newer browsers come out, your code will only become that much harder to upgrade. So you'll essentially receive two benefits from upgrading. You'll be on the latest version with all the latest bugfixes and easy-to-find documentation, and you'll be able to disable the autocomplete.